# Help with Unittest AttachPdf Class coverage

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I have the following class and unit test where i get the error, Invalid id:null

```
public with sharing class attachPDF {
    private final Facturatie__c a;
    public attachPDF(ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {
        a = (Facturatie__c) standardPageController.getRecord(); //instantiate the Facturatie__c object for the current record  
    }
    Facturatie__c currentRecord = [SELECT Id, Accountname__r.Name FROM Facturatie__c WHERE Id = : ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

    public PageReference attachPDF() {
        PageReference pdfPage = Page.Factuur2PDF;
        pdfPage.getParameters().put('id', a.id);
        Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent();

        Attachment attach = new Attachment(parentId = a.Id, Name = 'Factuur ' + '-' + currentRecord.Accountname__r.Name + '-' + date.today().format() + '.pdf', body = pdfBlob); //create the attachment object
        insert attach;
        PageReference pageWhereWeWantToGo = new ApexPages.StandardController(a).view();
        pageWhereWeWantToGo.setRedirect(true);
        return pageWhereWeWantToGo;
    }
}

@isTest
public class attachPDFTestClass {
    static testMethod void testAttachments() {

        PageReference pdfPage = new PageReference('/apex/attachPDF?id=');
        Test.setCurrentPage(pdfPage);

        Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.Name = 'null';
        insert testAccount;
        system.debug('Id Testaccount: ' + testAccount.Id);

        Facturatie__c currentRecord = new Facturatie__c(Accountname__c = testAccount.Name);
        currentRecord.Opportunity__r.Name = '2016-04-26 REALIANCE';
        currentRecord.Facturatie__c = '80% vooraf, 20% na oplevering';
        system.debug('Id currentRecord.Facturatie__c: ' + currentRecord.Facturatie__c);
        insert currentRecord;

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', currentRecord.Id);

        //currentRecord = [SELECT Id, testAccount.Name FROM currentRecord WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

        system.debug('Id currentRecord: ' + currentRecord.Accountname__r.Name);

        Facturatie__c a = new Facturatie__c(Accountname__c = testAccount.Name);
        insert a;
        system.debug('Id a: ' + a.Id);

        Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent();

        Attachment attach = new Attachment(parentId = a.Id, Name = 'Factuur ' + '-' + currentRecord.Accountname__r.Name + '-' + date.today().format() + '.pdf', body = pdfBlob); //create the attachment object
        insert attach;

        system.debug(attach.Name);
        System.assertEquals(attach.Name, 'Factuur-Test_Account-' + date.today().format() + '.pdf');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request parameters are case sensitive. In your case, you are setting `Id` in the test class and trying to get `id` in your attachPDF class. I think this is why you are getting the id as null.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked

```
static Account testAccount;
```

static {

```
testAccount = new Account();
testAccount.Name = 'REALIANCE';
insert testAccount;
```

}